# Large integer and arbitrary/multi precision floats for Vala

Tags: biginteger, vala, arbitrary-precision

Is there a way to use big integers or arbitrary precision types in vala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, no one made a binding yet: http://live.gnome.org/Vala/BindingsStatus, although there was some discussion about GMP & Vala operator overloading.

You'll have to bind one of the bignum libraries. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

Comment: yw, don't forget to share your binding (send a mail to vala-list, update the wiki, and attach it to a bug in bugzilla.gnome.org, don't forget to mention where to find the latest version). have fun!